# An R-linear map R/I to R

Tags: linear-algebra

I've found the following statement in the K. Conrad's note, Example 4.4 (http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/noetherianmod.pdf):

Let $I$ be an ideal in a ring $R$, then $Hom_R(R/I, R) \cong \{r\in R: Ir=0 \}$.

Why this is true?

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: As I understand, it's sufficient to dicide where 1(class containg 1) can go, but I don't understand how one can rewrite this condition in terms of ideal.

Comment: Suppose $\eta : R/I \rightarrow R$ is a homomorphsim then what can you say about $\eta(1+I)$??

Comment: $\eta(1+I)=\eta(1)+\eta(I)=1$ ?

Comment: That does not help... May be you should tell for what $r\in R$ can you have $\eta(1+I)=r$???

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20115/discussion-between-user44636-and-praphulla-koushik).

Comment: Fine... i have said something in the chat... Let me know if you can see that

Comment: I've answered. Check, please.

Comment: I am sorry, i was busy with some other question... i have posted some hints as an answer.. See if that helps..

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to construct a map $\varphi:R/I\to R$ which is $R$ linear. As suggested in the comments, you just need to choose $\varphi(1)$. The rest is determined automatically by $R$ linearity. By definition of the quotient, the element $1\in R/I$ is annihilated by $I$. Hence, $\varphi(1)$ also has to be annihilated by $I$.

In general, if $M,N$, are $R$ modules, $\varphi:M\to N$ is $R$ linear, and $m\in M$ is annihilated by the ideal $I$, then so is $\varphi(m)$. Indeed, for $i\in I$ we have $$i\varphi(m)=\varphi(im)=\varphi(0)=0.$$

Comment: Why if $1 \in R/I$ is annihilated by $I$ it implies that $\varphi(1)$ also be annihilated by $I$? Is the following reasoning o.k. : 
$I*\varphi(1+I)=\varphi(I+I^2)=\varphi(I)=0$ ?

Comment: @user44636 I added a paragraph to the answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Consider homomorphism $\eta: R/I \rightarrow R$ with $1+I\rightarrow r$

Now, we want to see what properties does this $r$ have....

We have $\eta(1+I)=r$ and for $m\in I$  we have $\eta(m(1+I))=m\eta(1+I)=mr$..

What is $m(1+I)$??? What is $\eta(m(1+I))$???

Comment: $m(1+I)=m+mI=0$ because of $\in I \Rightarrow $. 
$\eta(m(1+I))=\eta(0)=0$. So we get that $mr=0$. 
Yes?

Comment: @user44636 : Yes.... so??

Comment: so, I think we get the answer to the question.

Comment: and what is the answer???

Comment: The answer is that all $r$ should be annihilated by the ideal $I$.

Comment: that is it.... ..

Comment: Dear Praphulla Koushik ! 
Thank you a lot for patience and very clear explanation.

Comment: you are welcome... you still have to prove the isomorphism and i believe you can do that... good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

An approach is to consider the exact sequence $0\to I\to R\to R/I\to 0$ and applying $\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\Hom_R(-,R)$ that gives the exact sequence.
$$
0\to\Hom_R(R/I,R)\to\Hom_R(R,R)\to\Hom_R(I,R)
$$
Thus $\Hom_R(R/I,R)$ can be identified with the homomorphisms $R\to R$ whose restriction to $I$ is zero. Since the homomorphisms $R\to R$ are those of the form $\hat{r}:x\mapsto xr$, saying that $\hat{r}(I)=0$ is exactly the same as saying $Ir=0$.